Pulling out text patterns from short text fields
I was wondering if there was a good way to pull out text patterns from short text field in Snowflake. Not semantic value, literal value but noticing trends.
For instance, a text field (Freehand customer variables, input, whatever) ... might say the following
"Country_code"
"country_name"
"country_location"
"my_favorite_country"
Ideally, the pattern "country" would be pulled out a commonly repeated word. However, you would have no starting point in terms of what words to search for.
I suppose the issue would mostly be string splitting ... by spaces or underscores .. but what about cases where this isn't the case? "countrybluntry" ... is there a way of pulling out common character patterns ... like ... what's the most common patterns that are over 4 characters long?
Would this be prohibitive in SQL?

Maybe this could help.
Oracle:
The code is tested with Oracle but it uses basic string functions that could be  adjusted to any dialect except, maybe, Level Connect By part which could be (most probably) solved with a recursive cte or some other form of number generators.
With    --    S a m p l e    D a t a :
  tbl ( id, txt ) AS
    ( Select 1, 'Federal State Name' From Dual Union All
      Select 2, 'Name of the_favourite country' From Dual Union All
      Select 3, 'CounTRy_cODe' From Dual Union All
      Select 4, 'country location' From Dual Union All
      Select 5, 'My Favourite_country' From Dual Union All
      Select 6, 'Best_coffee_location' From Dual
    ),

... create a grid cte to extract the words out of txt column. I used underscore '_' as delimiter (it could be changed to something else) and transformed all letters to lowercase to avoid lettercase differences.
  grid  AS
    ( select Distinct
             id,  SubStr( d.txt_dlmtd, 
                          Instr(d.txt_dlmtd, '_', 1, LEVEL) + 1, 
                          Instr(d.txt_dlmtd, '_', 1, LEVEL + 1) - 
                                 Instr(d.txt_dlmtd, '_', 1, LEVEL) - 1
                        ) as element, 
             d.txt_dlmtd
      From ( Select   id, 
                      Lower(
                           Replace('_' || Replace(txt, ' ', '_') || '_', '__', '_')
                         ) as txt_dlmtd,
                     Length( Lower(
                                   Replace('_' || Replace(txt, ' ', '_') || '_', '__', '_')
                                  )
                           )
                            - 
                     Length(
                             REPLACE( Lower(
                                             Replace('_' || Replace(txt, ' ', '_') || '_', '__', '_')
                                           ), '_', ''
                                    ) 
                           ) - 1 as lngth  -- number of elements (words)
             From    tbl
          ) d
      Connect By LEVEL <= d.lngth   -- d.lngth is number of elements (words)
    )

--    M a i n    S Q L :
Select    g.element, Count(g.id) as  cnt 
From      grid g
Where     Length(element) > 4     -- filter to elements longer than 4 characters
Group By  g.element
Order By  Count(g.id) Desc, g.element

/*  R e s u l t : 
ELEMENT    CNT
---------  ---
country      4
favourite    2
location     2
coffee       1
federal      1
state        1    */

See the fiddle here.
